# Spring17 new favorites access

Tags: lightning, spring17

is their a mean to get access to the favorites defined by specific user in lightning ? We did'nt find any new salesforce object that is storing the new spring 17 lightning favorites. If salesforce isn't storing them in objects then how are they stored, and how can we access them in apex ?